# Application crashing when running into Android device when using ionic with MobileFirst

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to develop an application in using MobileFirst using ionic and Angular. My app runs fine as long as I am in preview but when running on a device I am getting strange errors.

```
10-20 14:48:27.185: D/CordovaWebView(17759): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: samsung
10-20 14:48:27.190: I/CordovaWebView(17759): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.
10-20 14:48:27.195: I/dalvikvm(17759): Could not find method android.webkit.CookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies, referenced from method com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin.initialize
10-20 14:48:27.195: W/dalvikvm(17759): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 512: Landroid/webkit/CookieManager;.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies (Landroid/webkit/WebView;Z)V
10-20 14:48:27.195: D/dalvikvm(17759): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001a
10-20 14:48:27.205: D/WML_SISO(17759): InitPasteboardJni
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2678)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$13100(WebViewCore.java:1361)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2790)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:3966)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:1020)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$2100(ZoomManager.java:57)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1581)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-20 14:48:27.245: W/webcore(17759):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 14:48:27.285: V/(17759): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
10-20 14:48:27.285: V/(17759): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
10-20 14:48:27.290: D/webkit(17759): Firewall not null
10-20 14:48:27.290: D/webkit(17759): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
```

Is it tied to specific version of cordova or app...kind of confused

Comment: Provide your project.

Comment: Where should I upload that ?

Comment: Whereever you want. Dropbox, Google Docs...

Comment: Entire project is uploaded in 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eehfk1wmkkmi50l/DoradoBankProject.zip?dl=0

Comment: Which device and Android OS are you testing this with?

Comment: Samsung SII, with OS level 4.0.4 and tab running with version 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I took the project and ran it in both the Mobile Browser Simulator (which really only previews the web resources and not any Android-specific code), as well as in the Android Emulator and the application worked in both - meaning it did not crash in the Android Emulator.

Check if this is specific to those Samsung devices, or also crashes in different brands as well, or whether it fails only in Android 4.x or also in 5.x (I tested in 5.x).

Comment: I just tried in 5.x device and did get expected result, looks like it is failing with 4.x version.